# Discrete Fourier Transform factorisation

Tags: numerical-methods, fourier-analysis

I've come upon the following question about the Fourier transformation

" Use $F_n x$ to determine the discrete Fourier transform of the vector $y=(x_0, x_2, ..., x_{2n-2})$ of the components of $x$ with even index"

The hint states that using the Fast Fourier transform factorisation splitting formula, but I haven't had any luck with it. Can someone please help me out?

Comment: I think you can try to define a new vector $z$ which contains all even components of $y$.

Comment: You know that $(F(z)+F(-z))/2$ produces the even part of the function, which in the case of polynomials is the sum of the even degree terms? Note that $-1=e^{i\pi}$.